# setTeams runs before the rest of the useEffect-code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm fetching some data from firebase firestore in my react app. This should be presented in an `ul`. When `useEffect` runs, setTeams runs before the data is fetched from firebase. How can I run setTeams after the data from firebase has been fetched?

```
useEffect(() => {
        const teamsList = []
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('members').where('user', '==', user.uid).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
                    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                        firebase.firestore().collection('teams').doc(doc.data().teamId).get().then((doc) => {
                            teamsList.push({
                                name: doc.data().name,
                                teamID: doc.data().teamId,
                            })
                            console.log('Her')
                        })
                    })
                    setTeams(teamsList)
                    console.log('Der')
                })
            } else {
                history.push("/logg-inn")
            }
        })
    }, [])
```

Comment: Could you extend the question with the useEffect code?

Comment: I've done it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reformatted your code with `async await` instead of `then` and I think it has better readability now:

Use `Promise.all` if you need to set a value based on multiple promises.

```
           useEffect(() => {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
    if (user) {
      const querySnapShot = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collectionGroup("members")
        .where("user", "==", user.uid)
        .get();
      const promises = querySnapshot.map((doc) => 
        firebase.firestore().collection("teams").doc(doc.data().teamId).get());
        const teams = await Promise.all(promises);
        const docs = teams.map((doc) => ({
          name: doc.data().name,
          teamID: doc.data().teamId,
        }));
        setTeams(docs);

        console.log("Der");
      
    } else {
      history.push("/logg-inn");
    }
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: I run into an error:
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Comment: I'm not  sure if that error is related to the useEffect, are you using object destructuring anywhere in your code?

Comment: Nope, im not using any object destructuring

Comment: I've debugged a bit now, and it happens somewhere in the useEffect

Comment: The problem is this line: ```const teams = await Promise.all(promises);```

Comment: @DanielOlsen can you log promises to see what it is?

Comment: Console.log(promises) returns undefined. Do you know why?

Comment: @DanielOlsen you have to go through every part of  ----querySnapshot.map((doc) => 
        firebase.firestore().collection("teams").doc(doc.data().teamId).get()); --- to see what's wrong. first log querySnapshot, then inside callback of map, check what is it returning

Comment: It's probably querySnapshot  that is undefined, is this line correct? isn't anything wrong with it? firebase
        .firestore()
        .collectionGroup("members")
        .where("user", "==", user.uid)
        .get();

Comment: I fixed it with doing ```const promises = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) =>```. I had to access the docs in the querySnapshot before mapping them. Anyways thanks for the help. You saved me from a big headache :)